# How do I share my photos and video?

Tags: windows-7, windows, file-sharing, windows-photo-gallery, photos

I have 1.8Tb of private photos and videos. I want my family to have access to this files.
I'm running a 24/7 home server using Windows 7, users will also have Windows 7.

Note: I don't want to upload photo to any service on the net. I just want to give a private access to my family to access this media. An application (Windows or Web) that handle gallery functionally on the top would be very nice.

**Update:** The users are not in the same network. They are on Internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your family members are ***not*** on the same network, I think IIS or Apache might be your best option.

Comment: I'm running IIS 7, but what services should I install on IIS?

Comment: If an enhanced web interface isn't a must, you could simply serve up the directories containing the files you wish to share. If you do wish to run things like a gallery on top of IIS, I'm not the best person to ask, since I personally only have experience running Apache. Hopefully someone else (or a web search) will be better able to help you with that.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 7 already has solutions for this; they're very easy to find with a quick search. You can put the shared items into the Public folder, and the default image viewer *is* a gallery viewer.

Simply enable Public Folder sharing, and put your files into the appropriate folders. Network discovery needs to be On. Details are [here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Sharing-files-with-the-Public-folder).

You may have your data on an external drive and wish to share that instead. Take a look at [File Sharing Essentials](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/File-sharing-essentials).

Comment: Apparently the family is *not* on the same network.

Comment: Ah. It's all in the details, isn't it.